# What's causing the difference in the footer between these two pages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

So I'm pretty sure this is a simple HTML mistake I'm missing...

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap to build my still under construction website.

The page with the working footer is [here](http://evamvid.github.io).

The page with the non-working footer is [here](http://evamvid.github.io/about/).

Working footer:

[image: Imgur]

Nonworking footer:

[image: Imgur]

The code for both of them (I copied and pasted from the working to the nonworking; nothing happened) is:

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
<p>
Built on <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Twitter's Bootstrap</a> with the <a href="http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/">Flat-UI Design Pack</a> and <a href="http://jquery.com/">JQuery</a>. Also uses <a href="http://fontawesome.io/">Font Awesome</a>.
</p>
</div>
</footer>
```

So the problem must be something higher up in the page; I just can't figure out what.

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the broken page can't load the CSS file http://evamvid.github.io/about/flat-ui/css/flat-ui.css

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the non working page does not have `flat-ui.css`.